# All of my WordPress sites have Bold Open Sans

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I have no idea what happened to all of my WordPress sites' dashboard. Every local site and even my production sites are using a bold Open Sans font. It is miserable and is driving me nuts. I need help in troubleshooting this, don't know where to begin.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. If anyone else has this issue here is the solution. 
- It ended up being a Creative Cloud problem. 
- Open up the creative cloud click assests and navigate to fonts. 
- From there you can enable and **disable** fonts. 
- Disabled the Open Sans and it fixed all my dashboards.